# Overriding argument(s) of a function call which is made within another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say, I have two functions `bar()` and `foo()`. `bar()` executes `foo()`.

```
def foo():
    try:
        num = int( input("need an Integer") )
    except ValueError:
        print("input invalid")


def bar():
    foo()
```

While I run `bar()` and type a non-integer value, I should obtain `"input invalid"` message. However, if I want to customize this error message `"input invalid"` in `bar()` **without** modifying `foo()`.
What should I do?

I've tried the following, but this does not work.

```
def foo():
    try:
        num = int( input("need an Integer") )
    except ValueError:
        print("input invalid")


def bar():
    try:
        foo()

    except Exception as result:  <-- this does not capture the error in foo()
        print("my customized error message")
```

Desired output is: `"my customized error message"` instead of `"input invalid"` (but if I can output both messages, it is acceptable)

Comment: Someone told me if I can obtain the "exit code" from `foo()`, then I can add error message in `bar()` based on the value of "exit code". But I am not sure how.

Comment: I think you received bad advice. An exit code is simply an integer returned by the function, traditionally 0 meaning success. Really only useful in Python if you are running the program from the command line and trying to return success/failure (see sys.exit()). You could still use an exit code, but it will add nothing to what you can accomplish by using try/except. By the time foo returns to bar, the message will be printed, so there's nothing you can do to substitute a different message. If you want bar to control what message is printed, then move the try/except to bar.

Comment: `print("my customized error message")` is bad practice. If it is an error message, it belongs on stderr.  Do not print error messages to stdout.

Comment: @Deepstop Thanks for your comment! I was provided with a couple of functions (`foo()`s) in a `.py` script. And I was asked to write another `.py` script (`bar()`) to execute those functions. However the original error messages in `foo()` are not user-friendly. As a result, I was asked to modify those messages. If I understand your words, I must ask the developer who gave me `foo()` to change his error messages, right?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, I am quite new to programming. I must look into stderr and stdout before I can understand your idea.

Comment: @JeffXi The solution from blhsing does exactly what you want it to. It will have to be extended if you have several different error messages you want to modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unittest.mock.patch` to temporarily override the built-in `print` function with a customized function that uses the original `print` function to print the desired message if the message passed in matches the message to be replaced, or otherwise print the message as-is:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def custom_print(s, *args, **kwargs):
    orig_print("my customized error message" if s == "input invalid" else s, *args, **kwargs)

orig_print = print

def bar():
    with patch('builtins.print', new=custom_print):
        foo()

bar()
```

Comment: This is really a smart solution!!

Answer (score 0):

You are basically on a good way. What you want to do is to `raise` an Exception in `foo` which you can catch in `bar`. This is done with the raise command as shown below:

```py
def foo():
    try:
        num = int( input("need an Integer") )
    except ValueError:
        raise Exception("input invalid")


def bar():
    try:
        foo()

    except Exception as e:
        print("my customized error message")
```

If you now execute `bar()` and raise your Exception, you can catch it in `bar()` and print another message. If you want to obtain the original message, you can do so by printing the `str(e)`.

Comment: The OP stresses that `foo` cannot be modified.